# Define constant through looping

Tags: php, constants

I try to define constant value through looping, but it got error:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant XXXXX - assumed 'XXXXX' in XX on line XX`

This is the code:

```
$q = "SELECT `Key`, `Value` FROM appconfig";
//I skip the line to read from database
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {
    define("'" . $fetch["Key"] . "'", $fetch["Value"]);
    //I try to echo $fetch["Key"] and $fetch["Value"] and it returns value
}
```

Something wrong with the code? I tried to define it manually and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the quotes, you don't need them:

```
define($fetch["Key"], $fetch["Value"]);
```